# Create x509 certificate and encrypt lots of data

Tags: c#, encryption, windows-10

I want to create an encrypted XML file. Encrypted as a whole.

I have one big class, which I serialize to a string. Then I convert it to bytes (f.e in one test case it takes `1128` bytes) and I want to encrypt those bytes.

I need to have a certificate which no admin user has access to, so I created my cert like this:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My -FriendlyName "XD" -NotAfter
(Get-Date).AddYears(10) -KeyAlgorithm RSA -KeyLength 2048 -Subject "test"
```

Then in my C# app I get to that cert by `.Subject` and I want to encrypt my bytes using it. The problem is, that I get the exception with `bad length` message, which suggest, that I want to encrypt too many bytes with RSA.

Now I know I can use AES or something else, but I need to have this key in the certificate in the store, so no one except admin user, which creates that cert has access to it. And as I've read the documentation for `New-SelfSignedCertificate` - it cannot create a cert with f.e `AES` key.

So my question here would be: Is there a way to create a cert with a particular key algorithm which would be able to encrypt at least 2-3k bytes?

Answer (score 1):

RSA can only encrypt messages that are smaller than the modulus of the key pair. Some bytes should be reserved for padding, and the exact number depends on the padding scheme you are using.

In practice, asymmetric algorithms like RSA are usually used for key transport, not directly for message encryption. If you have a long message, encrypt it with AES, using a random key. Then encrypt the AES key with RSA, using the public key of the message recipient.

Standards like TLS, PGP, and S/MIME use RSA in this way.

Comment: Yes, and I actually know that. But the problem is I cannot create a Windows cert with f.e `AES` key

Comment: @dabljues Right, and that's not what I suggested. Create an RSA key pair, put the public key in the certificate. The message sender encrypts *the AES key used for the message* using that certificate. The message itself is encrypted with AES. It doesn't work any other way.

Comment: The problem is, there's no message sending. It is an application for students, and they just cannot know what's in the encrypted xml file (and I use system cert, cuz they can `dotPeek` the executable). Then should I store encrypted AES key straight in code, then get the cert, decrypt the key, then decrypt the XML file?

Comment: @dabljues By "message", I am referring to "one big class, which I serialize to a string. Then I convert it to bytes (f.e in one test case it takes 1128 bytes) and I want to encrypt those bytes." In cryptography, "message" is a general term for the data you want to secure. I am not sure about the details of the application, but you should never include a symmetric or private key in code that you give to the people from whom you are trying to keep secrets.

Comment: Yes, but if it is encrypted? I mean, f.e `bytes[] encryptedKey = ...`. And then I decrypt it using the certificate, which user has no access to, then I guess its okay, right?

Comment: @dabljues You decrypt with a private key, but I think I see what you mean. If the user (aka "attacker") really can't access the private key, then it's okay.